# generate and embed file into doc programmatically

Tags: java, file, embed, doc

I have a project which generates a report (doc file) programmatically. I have a hard time finding a solution to the following problem:

I would like to create a text file (or another doc file, whatever) with a given content, then I want to embed this file into the report programmatically. (I guess it should be done with the help of OLE Objects).

I am finding solutions in vb, I need it in java!

Apache POI or Aspose.Words has this possibility?

If anyone had done this before, I would really appreciate a simple code example for this embbedding.

Thanks, cheers!